# "Unable to start program" error for web project

Tags: c#, silverlight, internet-explorer, iis

I have a Silverlight project that we use internally that I wrote - and since we've not had any need to work on it, it's been a while since I've opened the project. I opened it up this morning and everything is fine in terms of building, but whenever I try to debug I get the following error:

Unable to start program "http://mymachinename/mywebsite/index.aspx"

Of course, running it in Firefox works fine but no symbols are loaded. Running without debugging still throws the same error but IE loads up anyway...

Navigating to the website in IE works fine - SL app opens up, loads data etc etc, all looks good

I've Googled this all morning (usually quite good at finding info) and been through all the questions on SO and I can't figure out what's going on - there doesn't seem to be any messages in the event log, there are no messages in any VS output window, the w3wp just terminates immediately after starting (probably due to there being an error trying to open IE). I've tried reinstalling IE, cleaning/rebuilding, using local dev server, creating a new web project, turning on/off settings in IE9 etc etc

Nothing seems to make a difference - anyone got any experiences of this and has fixed it without doing one of the things I've already done? Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

Just to be clear in case anyone asks - I get this problem when creating a new web project - i.e. everything I said I'd tried (above) didn't change the behaviour. It showed the same error no matter what I'd done so far (that includes a NON SL web project)

I've also tried attaching the debugger to w3wp that is running (the standard IIS process) and I can't seem to get it to debug (no symbols are loading), but that might be another issue altogether. I'm going to look at that next and maybe if I figure that out it might lead to fixing this issue

UPDATE 2

Debugging in Firefox works - I attached to w3wp with no success, then realising my stupidity (SL being a client side app!) I attached to the plugin-container.exe that FF runs its plugins in. This works. I can probably do the same for IE and just attach to IE, but why won't it start up from VS?! *hair pull*

UPDATE 3

Just in case anyone asks, the default browser is set to IE in VS. Also I've managed to debug by attaching to IE, it just won't start IE from within VS - annoying but I can live with it for now. If anyone does have a suggestion though, feel free...

Comment: Have you tried to "clean" the solution or do a Rebuild?

Comment: In the question: "I've tried reinstalling IE, cleaning/rebuilding, using local dev server, creating a new web project, turning on/off settings in IE9 etc etc"

Comment: Nope, same issue with new web project - I'll edit the question so it's more clear that nothing worked

Comment: You could check if the default browser is set in VS to the one you want (eg. IE), maybe the internal one crashed

Comment: Done that already - it's set to IE as default. The internal one doesn't even get a look in

Comment: Just for the fun of it, try to debug it on another machine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone's information in case they have this same problem, it ended up being that the port I was running my site on was also running a SharePoint site!

I created a new site on port 81 and used that for dev - not sure what setting on the other site caused the issue but it ended up working on port 81.